# TypeError when trying to pass output of one function to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, typeerror

I'm trying to make a chat room/text message tool with python. I need to connect to the server with the `.connect() method`. Every time I go somewhere outside of my house and connect to wifi, my private ip address changes, so I want my code to adapt to that situation by passing `os.system("ipconfig getifaddr <wireless interface>")` to the `.connect()` method.

I found out this isn't correct after running my code, which raised a TypeError. I know this isn't correct because the `os.system()` function executed and printed my ip address to the console instead of passing that output to the function. I'm assuming that the function returned 0 to the function, indicating that nothing went wrong with the command, which is not my intention. I want the ip address to be passed to the function.

It's somewhat similar to bash, like this: `ipconfig getifaddr <wireless interface> > file.txt` where the output of the command is redirected to a file called `file.txt`

Here is my code:

**client.py**

```
import socket
import threading
import subprocess

nickname = input("Choose a nickname: ")
subprocess.run("./ipaddress.sh")

with open("ip_addr.txt", 'r') as f:
    file = f.readline()

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((file, 48812))

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if message == 'NICK':
                pass
            else:
                print(message)

        except:
            print("An error occurred!")
            client.close()
            break


def write():
    while True:
        message = f'{nickname}: {input("")}'
        client.send(message.encode('ascii'))


receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

I don't know if I also have to make changes in the server file but if I do here is the code for you to see as well:

**server.py**

```
import threading
import socket
import subprocess

subprocess.run("./ipaddress.sh")

with open("ip_addr.txt", 'r') as f:
    file = f.readline()

host = file
port = 48812

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)

        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            broadcast(f"{nickname} left the chat".encode('ascii'))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break
def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with{str(address)}")

        client.send("NICK".encode("ascii"))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print(f"Nickname of client is {nickname}\n")
        broadcast(f'{nickname}joined the chat!\n'.encode('ascii'))
        client.send("Connected to the server!\n".encode('ascii'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()


print("Server is listening...")
receive()
```

And here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthewschell/PycharmProjects/TCP Chat Room/server.py", line 14, in <module>
    server.bind((host, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

**EDIT:** Instead of using `os.system()`, like others don't recommend, I've used subprocess instead. It fixed the exception that `os.system()` raised but now it raises another exception. See the full traceback above. Also see the edited code above. Notice the new `with` statement to open a file created by a bash script containing the ip address in both files.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: instead of `os.system()` use `subprocess.run()` or other function in module `subprocess`. Even in documentation for [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) you have information about `subprocess`

Answer (score 0):

Your guess was correct os.system() returns the exit code of the subprocess, which is an integer (0 is success). What do you’re looking for is stdout from the subprocess and the best way to get that is to use the Python “subprocess” module instead of os.system.

```
>>> outcome = subprocess.run('/bin/date', capture_output=True)
>>> outcome.returncode
0
>>> outcome.stdout
b'Thu 11 Feb 2021 18:30:57 GMT\n'
>>>
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but i'm getting an `OSError` saying `Exec format error: ./ipaddress.sh`. I have a file called ipaddress.sh and I put the shebang and the path to bash at the top of the file. But when I execute it, i get that error

Comment: Ok I fixed the exec format error but now I get the same thing I got the first time, a TypeError not expecting an integer

Comment: You'll need to use "shell=True" if you want to subprocess.run a bash script. Otherwise it tries to launch the content of the script file directly as a binary executable, which it isn't and hence exec format error.